# Custom checkbox around a circular image

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, checkbox

Is there an easy way to use a custom check around a rounded image thumbnail? I'm looking to implement the checkbox as ring slightly larger than the thumbnail image when checked the checked state can represented by enabling the outer ring and when unchecked the ring should be invisible.I need to  inflate a gridview of thumbnails from a adapter,in which the above has to be implemented.Do I have to use an imageview and do my own logic myself?

Comment: did you check my answer?

Comment: no it didn't worked for me